# How can I play a sound from the command line in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, audio

I would like to play a short sound file from the command line in Mac OS X, independent of any audio player application, in order to provide notification that a long job has finished.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/969080/how-to-ring-the-system-bell-from-command-line ?

Comment: @VikasGoel While I suppose that the terminal bell could count as “playing a short sound file”, it can't ever play a _different_ sound file from the one configured as the system alert sound, so I would not count it as the same question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is a built-in tool: `afplay <sound file>`. The man page does not document all of its options, which can be found via `afplay -h`:

```
Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
```

It will not play more than one audio file.

Comment: afplay sometimes has this bug: http://superuser.com/questions/319174/error-audioqueuestart-failed-when-running-afplay-repeatedly . Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Careful with the `-v` option: a value of `1` seems to mean "100%"!

Comment: I discovered `--volume` or `-v` option is float as mentioned by @doctaphred. Don't use more than `1` if you have an external speaker

Answer (score 24):

One time, when the power went off at work, knowing that my firewall would return to that last state (powered on) when the electricty came back on, I wrote a script in bash that used the `say` command to wake me up when the power came back on.

Comment: I love abusing the `say` command.

Comment: Indeed, `say` is relevant to this sort of problem and a good alternate solution. Have a vote! I was looking specifically for playing a short sound, though, as hearing a phrase would get tiresome for my use case.

Comment: Interesting note: if you are remotely logged into a machine via ssh, `say` won't work unless you `sudo` it. (Much fun for making other people's computers talk to them.)

Answer (score 16):

Have you considered **`printf "\a\a\a"`** or **`echo -e "\a\a\a"`**?

Comment: For those that don't know this is the control sequence character for 'bell', which on most systems will make a 'bonking' sound