# "Error: AudioQueueStart failed" when running afplay repeatedly

Tags: macos, shell

Every time a run in Terminal the command:

```
while :; do
    afplay "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Nada/Bell.aif";
    sleep 10;
done
```

I get the expected result, but after a while the code stops working and I get error messages.

Error message:

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been running this for a few minutes now without any errors: `while :; do afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Hero.aiff; sleep 10; done`. So no idea really.

Comment: Thank you for testing Lri. I restarted the machine, reran the command  and it ran fine, but 5 hours later the error message appeared again. I wish it was a dictionary to understand AQMEIO_Base:: DoStartI0,  -66681, etc.

Comment: Hi, weeks later and I haven't found a solution. While running this script for hours, one can see in the Activity Monitor the process "afplay" appears repeated up to 3 or four times at the same time. When this happens I know that it is not working anymore and to top it off the sound in Finder dies too (Finder won't play sound files i.e. mp3s within itself) It seems that there is a time out problem. Should I add a "play in the background" command (&) How? Will this help? or a "stop afplay" completely before it starts over the loop? How? Any suggestion?      Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try running it in a subshell and on the background with `(afplay sound.aiff &)`. Or wrap it in an AppleScript or something... Or use launchd to run afplay repeatedly if that's an option.

Comment: I have created a small app using Automator: http://tinyurl.com/3o4rynb -- (the goal is to keep busy the sound card at least every 10 seconds) -- The app runs well as the command above but it will stop within hours in the same fashion: the "say" process will be invisible the first minutes but later it starts intermittently showing up for seconds, then for longer until it stops. The "say" process then will be visible all the time and the app actually is stock and not working (neither the computer has sound). I discover today that quitting "coreaudiod" service will reboot the sound. (??????????)