# How to ring the system bell from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, notifications, bell

I'm using some Bash scripts under Linux that require some time to complete; I'd like to add at the end of them a command to ring the system bell when those tasks are done, so I can be notified.

What's the proper command to do that? (please note that what I need is to be notified, with a sound and possibly with a message, so I can accept any solution in these regards).

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation is not very useful...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1974/1932

Comment: These solutions aren't working for me.

Comment: What does your research tell you? What *exactly* have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Check this answer, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep

Comment: I've tried the commands given on the answers to the linked question, but they aren't working

Comment: `( speaker-test -t sine -f 440 )& pid=$! ; sleep 0.4s ; kill -9 $pid` requires ALSA installed. Always [from one of that answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163716/66388)

Comment: I think you can find interesting an answer [about notification of slhck](http://superuser.com/a/345455/257269); the second part.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I tried to reinstall ALSA and now it works. I don't know why, but even it if was installed before, it didn't work; if someone wants to put their suggestions on these commands on a full answer, I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 83):

```
tput bel
```

is a relatively portable solution.

Comment: "tput bel" works on macOS, as it should.

Comment: Works on Cygwin bash terminal as well.

Comment: Works on CentOS 7 bash via macOS terminal.

Comment: works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running in Windows 10 with WSL2.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 35):

Try this command:

```
echo -e "\07"
```

or

```
echo -e "\a"
```

They are the same. "07" is an octal representation of BEL (bell) character in ASCII, and "a" stands for "alert", the letter is probably easier to remember. As mentioned in the comments, the -e switch enables escape sequences. Also, you can append a message directly after the escape character like this: "\aSuccess!".

Comment: N.B. The `-e` is needed to enable interpretation of the `\07` escape sequence.

Comment: Works on Cygwin bash terminal as well.

Comment: replacement for -e is dollor sign: `echo  $'\a'`

Comment: @PeymanMajidi The `$'\a'` format is a function of the shell, not the `echo` command; I'm guessing some shells won't support it.